# django view render to template from another app

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to render to a template from another app but not sure how to import or if I should be importing with templates?

The structure is

```
project->
    main app->
       templates->
         pages->
           home.html
         account ->
    current app->
       views.py
```

my views.py file sits within the current app and is trying to access templates within the main app (in the pages subfolder).

How would I render to it:

```
def temp_view(request):
    ....
    return render(request, "home.html",context)
```

Comment: What isn't working? It most likely should be `pages/home.html`

Comment: You would use `"pages/home.html"`, and Django will take care of it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At first you should have most probably configure your templates static path in **settings.py** with something similar to this

```py
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

`APP_DIRS=True` means Django will look for templates in each app directory in your case `main_app/` and `current_app/`:

you have simply to mention the template path considering this as root path, so simply:

```
def temp_view(request):
   ....
   return render(request, "pages/home.html",context)
```

Django will look under `main_app/` **directory** to find the **file** `pages/home.html`

Comment: Thanks - didn't realise it was as simple as that "pages/home.html". I tried importing and all sorts of weird things.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be simpler to create the view in the same app you would like to render?

```
from mainapp.models import mainappmodel
def currentappview(request):
    all = mainappmodel.objects.all()
    return render(request, "pages/home.html", {'all': all})
```